# Need help reviewing Mathematica expression which came from Physics

Tags: matrix, physics

Please help me check the conversion of these two expressions in physics to their respective Mathematica expression. Where sigma is the Pauli matrices in standard form, E/p0 is energy, m is mass and p is the momentum.

[image]

For eq(5.29)
I got:

```
w = ((e + m)/(2*m))^(1/2) {{1 + p3/(e + m), (p1 - (I *p2))/(e + m), 0,
 0}, {(p1 + (I* p2))/(e + m), 1 - p3/(e + m), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
1 - p3/(e + m), -((p1 - (I* p2))/(e + m))}, {0, 
0, -((p1 + (I* p2))/(e + m)), 1 + p3/(e + m)}}
```

And for eq(5.30)

```
P = (m^(-1))*((\[Gamma]0*p0) +(\[Gamma]1*p1) + (\[Gamma]2*
   p2) + (\[Gamma]3*p3));
```

Where,

```
\[Gamma]0 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
\[Gamma]1 = {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}};
\[Gamma]2 = {{0, 0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, I, 0}, {0, I, 0, 0}, {-I, 0, 0, 0}};
\[Gamma]3 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[Sigma]p=Sum[PauliMatrix[i]*Symbol["p"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,3}]
Id2=IdentityMatrix[2];
O2=IdentityMatrix[2]*0;

wExp=(IdentityMatrix[4]+ArrayFlatten[{{\[Sigma]p/(e+m),O2},{O2,-\[Sigma]p/(e+m)}}])*Sqrt[(e+m)/(2m)];
%//MatrixForm
```

results in

> [image: wExp]

while

```
\[Sigma]phat=Sum[PauliMatrix[i]*Symbol["phat"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,3}];
PExp=(ArrayFlatten[{{O2,Id2},{Id2,O2}}]*p0+ArrayFlatten[{{O2,\[Sigma]phat},{-\[Sigma]phat,O2}}]*p)/m;
%//MatrixForm
```

results in

> [image: P]

The expression for `w` given by OP coincides with `wExp` while `P` and `PExp` differ since no explicit definitions for the expressions $\hat{p}$ and $p$ in Eq. (5.30) where given in the question. I would invite OP to fill in the blanks/expressions for $p$ and $\hat{p}$.

Comment: p={px,py,pz}//3 vector form, yeah I think the expression match thanks.